# How to count numbers of rows in Excel data sheet?

Tags: excel

I have two columns:

```
1st model name (ABC)
2nd model year (2013 or 2014)
```

An example of the data is like this:

```
model name       Model Year
ABC                2013
ABC                2014
ABC                2013
ABC                2013
ABC                2013
```

I have more data than this.

How can i count the total number where model `name = ABC` and model `year = 2013`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First way:

```
=COUNTIFS(A2:A100,"ABC", B2:B100,2013)
```

Second way (if you have excel 2003):

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A2:A100="ABC")*(B2:B100=2013))
```